# Stop web scraping script when number of page is over

Tags: python, html, loops, web-scraping

I'm working with the Http-requests module of python to web scrape a website for particular info. My problem is I'm in a loop and I want my script stops when the number of pages is over. I know there is a solution with beautiful soup but I'm using the Http requests module for doing this project. Anyone can help me, please?

```
from requests_html import HTML, HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()

page = 0

none_num = 0

while none_num <= 2:

    website = session.get(f'https://emploi.educarriere.ci/nos-offres?page1={page}&page=offres&codes=&typeemploi1=&niveau1=&mots_cles=&anciennete=&typeoffre=&recruteur=')

    jobs = website.html.find('#myList')
    
    if jobs != None:

        jobs = website.html.find('li')

        for job in jobs:
            
            try:
                title = job.find('h4', first=True).text
                print(title)
                l_descriptions = job.find('.entry-title', first=True).text
                print(l_descriptions)
                redirect_web = job.find('h4 a', first=True).attrs['href']
                print(redirect_web)
                date_contents = job.find('.text-col.col-md-12', first=True).text
                limit_date = list(date_contents)
                limit_date=''.join(limit_date)
                limit_date = limit_date[52:62]
                print(f'Date limite: {limit_date}.')
                print()
                

            except Exception as e:
                title = None
                l_descriptions = None
                redirect_web = None
                limit_date = None
    else:
        jobs == None
        none_num+=1

    page +=1


print(page)
```

Comment: What does "number of pages is over" mean?

Comment: How do you intend knowing the total number of pages??

Comment: I actually don't know the total number of pages. Or I do know but it can change over time. So I want my script to be able to detect in a way if it reaches the total pages or not.

Comment: For this website I'am working on,  It has 20 pages. But in a couple of weeks, it can be 15 or 30 pages. So I want the script being able to know when to stop the loop that I have created at the beginning

Comment: You scrape the website then, to get the maximum page number at anytime. Get your while loop to break once this max page number is reached.

Comment: So I should first scrape all the website to get the maximum page number and then, I redo again the scraping ?? My real problem is how to help the script knows it's the max number of page.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken time to look at the source of the page you are trying to scrape, has an html select element at the end of the page. With this information, i have written the script below to get you the maximum page number.

```
import requests
import collections
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("https://emploi.educarriere.ci/nos-offres?page1=1&page=offres&codes=&typeemploi1=&niveau1=&mots_cles=&anciennete=&typeoffre=&recruteur=")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
result = soup.find('select', attrs = {'name' : 'page1'}).text
mycounter = collections.Counter(result)
max_page = result[-mycounter['0']:]
print(max_page)
```

You may now change the 'while' loop in your code to a 'for' loop like this:

```
for pagenum in range(2, max_page):
    #the remain portion of your code
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried to follow your idea and it's working now :-)